# How do I get the lava in my lava fountain to flow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on a multiplayer server and am trying to create a lava fountain in front of my door.  I have it enclosed in an area so the lava won't block any routes.  The only problem is that I can't get the lava to flow.  I've been told that I just need to put a bucket on top of a block and it should start flowing if I've got a step layout going down around the lava, but it doesn't work, the lava just disappears.  Please let me know if I need multiple buckets or am missing something.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Multiplayer in minecraft isn't quite working fully at the minute. What you're trying to do would work in single player survival, though.

To do this you use the bucket (right click) on the lava source to get a bucket of lava, then use the bucket again where you want the source to be dropped.

Comment: Part of the reason I was asking is because multiple of my friends on the server actually have done it. They don't seem to think I'm screwing something up but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Notch has already disclaimed that the multiplayer doesn't work correctly. Although by some suggestions, the actions may be taking place, just not reflected in the user client. Personally, I've had no problem with springs in the single player mode, but I've noticed that springs don't act correctly when I've been running a multiplayer game. For example, I find it difficult to remove water springs without replacing them with a solid block.

Comment: Meant to add: Try it in single player mode and if you can get it work, then you're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: I'm just going to note that they the people I was referring to actually had privileges to spawn Lava flows. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be adressing both water and lava in this answer.

First of all, Lava sources, unlike water does not spread on the overworld. ([more info..](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/is-there-any-way-to-cause-lava-source-blocks-to-replicate-in-minecraft/10024#10024))

Now, SMP still has [several bugs](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Known_bugs_in_Survival_Multiplayer), one of which is a problem with the bucket handling on the server. This is typically shown, as your bucket emptying and the water or lava you just placed suddenly dissapearing.

Luckily, the Modding community has already made a fix for the server for this problem as a class replacement for the server(as part of [llamacraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1012&t=23483))

**This class replacement has to be done on the server by the server administrator.**

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not working in Minecraft Multiplayer (but works in single-player).  See [Minecraft SMP bugs](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Known_bugs_in_Survival_Multiplayer) for this and more bugs in Survival Multiplayer.

As a work-around, most players find a natural source of water/lava and craft around it to get it to flow wherever they want it to flow.

**[Edit]** I've noticed that water and lava work on some unmodded servers, but not others.  On the ones that lava *does* work, it seems like it flows down but rarely outwards (water flows outwards though).  Try placing your lava on a wall rather than the ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to get water/lava to flow in minecraft this minute without waiting for the next update, you can use the server command to give yourself a block of water/lava and place it.  That block will then flow as normal.