# Why can I move water in Minecraft SMP Alpha?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is water movable on an SMP alpha server?  Last night I tried to make a greenhouse with water for the crops and every time I dropped the water in the trench it did not spread and disappeared within 3-4 seconds.  Is this a known issue or is there a trick to get this working in alpha SMP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Lava Spring (or flow) in Minecraft](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8295/creating-a-lava-spring-or-flow-in-minecraft)

Comment: [Related](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Known_bugs_in_Survival_Multiplayer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8295/creating-a-lava-spring-or-flow-in-minecraft/8434#8434), this doesn't work correctly at the moment (hopefully he'll fix it in the [halloween update](http://minecraft.net/boo)).

However, for now there *are* a few things you can do:

- If you are an admin, you can give yourself water (id# 8) or lava (id# 10) blocks:

  ```
  /give username 08 64
  /give username 10 64
  ```
- If you own the server, there are mods you can install which fix buckets.  I can't get the links for you right now, but I believe the name of the mod is llama-mod.

Answer (score 5):

Water and buckets now work correctly in SMP servers. This was a bug with an older version of Minecraft.