# Is there a way to collect obsidian on the world surface in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I want to make an obsidian farm. Unfortunately I have only 1 bucket of lava. Now the question is is it possible to make any obsidian farm on the earth surface or are there any rules stating otherwise?

Comment: See [my question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/) about getting lava to replicate.  Since the only way to get practically unlimited obsidian from a single lava bucket was a bug that got fixed, the answer is basically no.

Comment: Assuming multiplayer, you can build a portal to the Nether, have player in overworld break it, then return through the nether-portal.  A new portal will appear in the overworld, resulting in as much obsidian as you can mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, minecraft doesn't really check if you're on the surface or not for making obsidian, so any farms that work underground will also work overground.

There's a farm design that only needs one bucket of lava which is not consumed. You will be able to get 1 obsidian for every 1 redstone dust you have.

Here's a gif I made if you want to know how to make/use the farm:
http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/4127/h0q.gif

Here's the minecraft wiki page on obsidian farming:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Obsidian_farming

Here's also a video tutorial (Not mine) showing the same thing:

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this?

Comment: @shanodin Unsure of what version video is in, but it has been on for ages and still works as of the latest snapshot and 1.6.2.

Comment: @colorfusion: Have you tried it (and can prove so)?  I'm pretty sure it got fixed in the update after it was discovered.

Comment: @MBraedley Yep I've tried it. The .gif I linked was made just for this question in the latest version of minecraft.

Comment: Okay, just tested it myself.  It does still work.

Comment: This bug was fixed in 1.8

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The only way you can make obsidian on the surface is to find a surface lava pool or move lava from the Nether/cave and put it down on the surface (and then turn it into obsidian in the normal way)</strike>

You can't 'farm' obsidian in the way you can farm wheat/melon etc. - you can only have as much obsidian as you have lava.

Edit - there is a way of [mining infinite obsidian using redstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Obsidian_farming#Redstone-To-Obsidian_Glitch_.28.22Infiniobsidian.22.29).

Comment: Did Infiniobsidian get fixed?

Comment: Yeah, that bug apparently got fixed soon after it was found.

Comment: @MBraedley Redstone->Obsidian still works fine, even in the latest snapshot and 1.6.2.

Comment: This bug was fixed in 1.8